# Linux: how to determine the DMA address corresponding to what's returned from ioremap

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, dma

Say I have some physical address (this is the bus location of my DMA source peripheral):

```
phys_addr = 0xffff0000;
```

and I do:

```
virt_addr = ioremap(phys_addr, PAGE_SIZE);
```

And after doing this I no longer have direct access to `phys_addr` (In my case, I do not have access because the driver I am writing was passed only `virt_addr`).

My first failed attempt:

```
wrong_phys_addr = virt_to_dma(dev,virt_addr);
```

As an aside, I have no idea why the device `dev` is relevent in this lookup ...

This, of course, did not work because the `virt_addr` is not direct mapped kernel memory.  The [DMA-API](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) seems to suggest that all the `virt_to_bus`-like translations are deprecated and everyone should be using `dma_map_single` and the like to get the DMA bus address.  So I next tried this:

```
wrong_phys_addr = dma_map_single(dev, virt_addr, size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

Again this still does not work.  Of course, if I use `0xffff0000` directly as the source DMA address to `device_prep_dma_memcpy` everything works great -- but again I cannot do this because I do not have direct access to it.  The only possible way I can think of obtaining it is walking the kernel's pages tables ... I really don't want to have to do this manually.  Is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

```
struct page *kmap_to_page(void * vaddr)
```

Looks promising.  I'm not sure if the virtual addresses returned from ioremap would work with this.  Another possibility is

```
struct page* vmalloc_to_page(void* vmalloc_addr)
```

I need to investigate further.

Comment: Physical addresses are not necessarily the same as DMA addresses. Anyway, `dma_map_single()` should work. And why does the driver does not have access to its device's resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `vmalloc_to_page` was what I was looking for. If I do:

```
phys_addr = page_to_phys(vmalloc_to_page(virt_addr)))
```

this yields, `phys_addr == 0xffff0000`.

Following CL.'s advise I also tried doing all the following:

```
wrong_phy_addr1 = dma_map_single(dev, 0xffff0000, size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
wrong_phy_addr2 = dma_map_single(dev, virt_addr, size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
correct_phy_addr = phys_to_dma(dev, 0xffff0000);
```

After running this I get:

```
wrong_phy_addr1 == 7fff0000
wrong_phy_addr2 == 4091e000
correct_phy_addr == ffff0000
```

Thus, it looks like `phys_to_dma()` wins out here.  Using this method is preferable to using the raw physical address because (as CL. suggested), physical addresses are not necessarily DMA addresses -- On my board they just happen to be the same.

**In conclusion**, this is the answer to my original question:

```
dma_addr = phys_to_dma(dev, page_to_phys(vmalloc_to_page(virt_addr));
```

That being said, this extra lookup is expensive and could be avoided if the phys_addr (0xffff0000) were available to my driver -- I will look into changing the interface.

Before accepting my own answer, I'll give others some time to provide their own (better?) answers.

Comment: I wander why dma_map_single(dev, virt_addr, size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE) did not work. , maybe it should be DMA_TO_DEVICE ?